# Hue/saturation adjustment by ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick

When I scan a old book that is turned yellow, I remove the yellow by using Photoshop like this.

1. open `Adjustment -> Hue/Saturation`
2. select `Yellows` and set Lightness to 100
3. select `Reds` and set Lightness to 100

By this operation I can remove the unnecessary color clearly.
(Gray scale does not work like this.)

But not everybody have a Photoshop and I think ImageMagick can do same thing.
So I tried to find the options for that operation in ImageMagick, but I could not find it.

How can I remove yellow color from a aged book?

Comment: I think that [this script](http://www.fmwconcepts.com/imagemagick/colorbalance/index.php) will have you covered.  Not exactly sure how the colors map between the photoshop way and the Imagemagick way, however.

Comment: Thanks for info. I tried with `colorbalance -c r -a 0 input.jpg output.jpg`. But it does not remove specified color from the image.